# Run desktop game on web

Tags: java, php, web-applications, web, japplet

I have made games in jar format using processing.org, Netbeans and Eclipse! These are desktop based games I want to run these games on online servers (web) without altering the code. This game also have embedded sounds and graphics in its folder. Please help me out I am new to web app development?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just take a desktop application and put it somewhere and make it work in a webbrowser and multiuser magically.

You need to change code if you want your desktop application to become a webapplication.

It's a completely different development process.

Comment: Have you tried the magic word, "abracadabra!"

Comment: @Davos555 I have, and it turned my shoes into bananas :(

Answer (score 3):

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. direct from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.